# Neo4j Cypher Seting string of numbers to a date

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a dataset that has dates set as a string of numbers. In a query, I can convert the string to date but I keep getting an error when I try to set the property as the new date:

Currently: **a.saleDate = 201805 (string)**
I want: **a.saleDate = 2018-05 (date)**

**I can Query the saleDate as a Date with:**

```
MATCH (a:sale)
WITH [tointeger(substring(a.saleDate, 0, 4)), 
tointeger(substring(a.saleDate, 4))] AS dateComponents
RETURN date({year: dateComponents[0], month: dateComponents[1]}) AS date
```

**But when I try to SET the new Date with:**

```
MATCH (a:sale)
WITH [tointeger(substring(a.saleDate, 0, 4)), 
tointeger(substring(a.saleDate, 4))] AS dateComponents
SET date({year: dateComponents[0], month: dateComponents[1]}) = a.saleDate
RETURN a
```

**I get the error:**

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '=': expected whitespace, comment or '.'

Any help would be appreciated by a nubie to Cypher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I can see:

1. assignment is backwards; `a.saleDate` should be on the left
2. you don't carry `a` in your `WITH` caluse but you try to use it later

Try this...

```
MATCH (a:sale) 
WITH a, [tointeger(substring(a.saleDate, 0, 4)), tointeger(substring(a.saleDate, 4))] AS dateComponents 
SET a.saleDate = date({year: dateComponents[0], month: dateComponents[1]}) 
RETURN a
```

That all said, why not this...

```
MATCH (a:sale) 
SET a.saleDate = date(a.saleDate) 
RETURN a
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!
Carry the "a" in the WITH  clause makes sense and worked!
So did the much simpler SET a.saleDate = date(a.saleDate)  It just never occurred to me that I could do that as a string, much simpler!